# Approximate Holder continuous functions by smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation, holder-spaces

Let $g \in C^{\alpha} (B_1)$ be given. Can we find a sequence $(f_n) \subset C^{\infty} (B_1)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $C^{\alpha}(\overline{B_1})$? If so, how can it be done?

I have tried using the method to show that given $g \in C_0(B_1)$, there exists $(f_n) \subset C^{\infty} (B_1)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $C(\overline{B_1})$, that is, I make use of the modllifier $\varphi_\varepsilon$ and consider $g \star \varphi_\varepsilon$, then

$$|g \star \varphi_\varepsilon (x) - g(x)| \leq \int_{B_1} \varphi(z)|g(x - \varepsilon z) - g(x)|dz \rightarrow 0$$ uniformly since $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Using the approach, the only fact I need to show is $[g \star \varphi_\varepsilon - g]_\alpha \rightarrow 0$ as well. However, this is where I got stuck. If I try to calculate the semi-norm directly, then we have $$[g \star \varphi_\varepsilon - g]_\alpha = \sup_{x \neq y} |\int_{B_1} \varphi(z) \frac{(g(x - \varepsilon z) - g(x)) - (g(y - \varepsilon z) - g(y))}{|x - y|^{\alpha}}dz|$$ and I have no idea how can I proceed.

I believe this is a standard and elementary approximation problem, but I have yet to find any text that give light to this problem and spent quite some time on it. So, could anyone give me some kind of directions or answers? It would then be a great help to my studies and thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x-\epsilon z$ is outside $\overline{B_1}$, how do you define $g(x-\epsilon z)$?

Comment: That's why I consider $g \in C_0^{\alpha}(\overline{B_1})$ instead of $g \in C^{\alpha}(\overline{B_1})$. If $g \in C_0^{\alpha}(\overline{B_1})$, then $g(x) = 0$ for $|x|$ close to 1, say $|x| > 1 - \delta$ for some small $\delta$. So, for $\varepsilon < \delta/ 2$, $g_\varepsilon (x) = g \star \varphi_\varepsilon (x)$ is defined on $B_{1 - \delta + \varepsilon}$ and we can extend the function to be zero outside.

Comment: Of course, one should also take care of the case where one point is inside $B_{1 - \delta + \varepsilon}$ and one point is outside $B_{1 - \delta + \varepsilon}$ in the semi-norm. But I *think* it can be done so I haven't pay to much attention to it.

Comment: I see. Usually the notation $C_0^\alpha (\overline{B_1})$ means that the function is zero on the boundary. The standard notation for functions with compact support is $C_0^\alpha (B_1)$.

Comment: I could prove the convergence for every $0<\beta<\alpha$, but until now, I could not prove the convergence for $\alpha$...

Comment: @Tomás: Thank you so much! Well, come to think of it, $C_0^{\alpha} (B_1)$ is indeed the standard notation and sorry for misleading you. And yes, I also proved the convergence for every $0 < \beta < \alpha$, which is not difficult, yet it is far from implying the convergence for $\alpha$, for which the statement is false... Again, thank you so much for the link and everything! :D

Comment: You are welcome @user43378

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a counterexample in this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29869/density-of-smooth-functions-under-holder-metric), however I would like to note that for every $0<\beta<\alpha$ we do have convergence. Indeed, define for $x\neq y$  $$T(\epsilon,x,y)=\int_{B_1}\left|\varphi(z)\frac{g(x-\epsilon z)-g(x)-(g(y-\epsilon z)-g(y))}{|x-y|^\beta}\right|.$$

Case 1: $|x-y|\ge \delta_1$

In this case we have that for any $\eta>0$, there is $\epsilon_1>0$ such that if $\epsilon<\epsilon_1$ then

$$T(\epsilon,x,y)\leq 2\frac{\|\varphi\|_\infty}{\delta_1^{\alpha-\beta}}\left|B_1\right|\eta.\tag{1}$$

To prove $(1)$, use the uniform continuity of $g$ and the fact that $\frac{1}{|x-y|}\leq \frac{1}{\delta_1}$.

Case 2: $|x-y|<\delta_1$

In this case we use the $\alpha$-Hölder continuity of $g$ to conclude that for any $\epsilon>0$, $$T(\epsilon,x,y)\leq 2\|\varphi\|_\infty \left|B_1\right|\left|x-y\right|^{\alpha-\beta}\leq 2\|\varphi\|_\infty \left|B_1\right| \delta_1^{\alpha-\beta}.\tag{2}$$

We choose a suitable $\delta_1$ and combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to conclude that $$g\star\varphi_\epsilon\to g\ \mbox{in}\ C^{\beta}(\overline{B_1}).$$